# how can I design a RAII file descriptor without creating a new int

Tags: c++, c++11, file-descriptor, raii

I want to create a RAII wrapper around a file descriptor. As the object might be passed around threads, it really is a shared resource: this is why I made a first implementation by using a `shared_ptr` with a custom destructor.

```
struct file_descriptor
{
    file_descriptor( const std::string & pathname, int flags )
        :m_fd( initialize( pathname, flags ) )
    {
    }

    file_descriptor( const int opened_fd )
        :m_fd( initialize( opened_fd ) )
    {
    }

    operator int() const { return *m_fd; }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> initialize( const int opened_fd )
    {
        std::shared_ptr<int> ptr_to_fd;

        try
        {
            int * shared_fd = new int;
            ptr_to_fd = std::shared_ptr<int>( shared_fd, file_descriptor_closer() );
            *shared_fd = opened_fd;
        }
        catch( std::bad_alloc & )
        {
            close( opened_fd );
            throw;
        }

        return ptr_to_fd;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<int> initialize( const std::string & pathname, int flags )
    {
        const int fd = open( pathname.c_str(), flags );        
        if (fd < 0)
            throw std::system_error( std::error_code(errno, std::system_category() ), "cannot create file descriptor" );

        return initialize( fd );
    }
    std::shared_ptr<int> m_fd;
};
```

The custom destructor, is pretty simple:

```
struct file_descriptor_closer
{
    void operator()(int * const fd) noexcept { if (fd) close(*fd); delete fd; }
};
```

Now I find the design horrible, namely because of the "new int". I thought about making a custom allocator to point to an already-allocated block, but that seems overkill. Do you guys have suggestion to simplify this?

Comment: Consider using `std::shared_ptr<file_descriptor>` instead

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: I can’t: that would require rewriting all the code that uses this class. Also, it changes the "contract" of the class, in the sense that the user of the class will then be in charge of sharing the resource. Right now the `shared_ptr` is an implementation detail, hidden from users.

Comment: `shared_ptr` represents a lifetime semantic and really shouldn't be hidden. The flaws in the design of `file_descriptor` should be a clear indication of flaws in the rest of your design. I suggest addressing those as a whole and use `std::shared_ptr<file_descriptor>` otherwise your design will continue to suffer and become increasingly difficult to maintain.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious could you elaborate on why having a `std::shared_ptr` as part of the implementation of a class is a flaw? I don’t get that part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, you're mixing responsibilities.  Let your RAII class deal with the opening and closing of the file descriptor.  Let some other class deal with the lifetime question of your RAII class.  As you have it now, the user of your file_descriptor class would need to know that it is using a `shared_ptr` internally.  On first glance, if I were to share a file_descriptor between threads, I'd be making a `shared_ptr<file_descriptor>` of my own to counter the problem that I don't really know that internally it's already doing one.

Comment: I believe this is what Captain Obvlious meant in his original comment but now I understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

use some gentle violence:

```
struct file_descriptor_closer
{
    void operator()(void* fd) noexcept { if (fd) close(reinterpret_cast< int >(fd)); }
}; 
struct file_descriptor
{
    file_descriptor( const std::string & pathname, int flags )
        :m_fd( initialize( pathname, flags ) )
    {
    }

    file_descriptor( const int opened_fd )
        :m_fd( initialize( opened_fd ) )
    {
    }

    operator int() const { return reinterpret_cast< int >(m_fd.get()); }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<void> initialize( const int opened_fd )
    {
        try
        {
            return std::shared_ptr< void >( reinterpret_cast< void* >( opened_fd ), file_descriptor_closer() );
        }
        catch( std::bad_alloc & )
        {
            close( opened_fd );
            throw;
        }
    }

    std::shared_ptr<void> initialize( const std::string & pathname, int flags )
    {
        const int fd = open( pathname.c_str(), flags );        
        if (fd < 0)
            throw std::system_error( std::error_code(errno, std::system_category() ), "cannot create file descriptor" );

        return initialize( fd );
    }
    std::shared_ptr<void> m_fd;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not create your own container? What about something like:  http://ideone.com/m3kmaJ or with static counter: http://ideone.com/Gs4Kb7

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <atomic>

class FD
{
    private:
        int fd;
        static int count;

    public:
        FD(const char* FilePath, int flags) : fd(open(FilePath, flags)) {++FD::count;}
        FD(const FD& other) : fd(other.fd) {++FD::count;}
        FD(FD&& other) : fd(other.fd) { other.fd = -1; }

        ~FD()
        {
            FD::count -= 1;
            if (FD::count == 0)
            {
                std::cout<<"Destroyed\n";
                if (is_open())
                    close(fd);
            }
        }

        bool is_open() {return fd != -1;}
        FD* operator &() {return nullptr;}
        operator int() {return fd;}

        FD& operator = (FD other)
        {
            fd = other.fd;
            FD::count += 1;
            return *this;
        }

        FD& operator = (FD&& other)
        {
            fd = other.fd;
            other.fd = -1;
            return *this;
        }
};

int FD::count = 0;

int main()
{
    FD fd = FD("Unicode.cpp", O_RDONLY);
    FD copy = fd;
    FD cpy = FD(copy);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wait, did you just replace my `new int` with another `new int`? :)

Comment: and your `shared_ptr`.. and yes I did. It's a small reference counter. Unless you prefer to use a `static int` for counting..

Comment: So I still have a `new int`, but now I am implementing `std::shared_ptr` myself? am I missing something?

Comment: Fine then you can just make the counter static if you hate memory allocations that much: http://ideone.com/Gs4Kb7

Comment: @JoelFalcou Maybe so, but when you figure out a better way other than `reinterpreting` an `int` as a `void pointer` or creating a `new int` on the heap to stick into the `shared_ptr` like OP doesn't want, let me know then. I'll live with the down-votes though. Not a big deal. Read the answer above mine by: Andre. It's a good view on the original problem.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames i didn't down voted you ;) The correct solution is to refactor the code itself to use std::shared_ptr<file_descriptor> firectly.